# Javascript function.. Named?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I'm having difficulty understanding this code. It's not the typical Javascript function syntax that i'm familiar with. Is this a named function? Or is this a callback for the update event? Sorry for noobie questions, i'm fairly new to JS. I understand everything that's going on, except this function syntax
`foo: function(){};` which seems to happen a lot with an api tutorial i'm following.

```
updateProgress: function () {    
  $.post('/callback', {
    progress: plnzVideoTracker.progress
  });   
}
```

Comment: It's probably part of an object literal. Please post the complete code. As it stands, it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a object method ("literal"). The code you've included should be wrapped in an object. For example:

```
var SomeObject = {
  updateProgress: function () {    
    $.post('/callback', {
      progress: plnzVideoTracker.progress
    });   
  }
}
```

Within the object, you can refer to the method via `this.updateProgress()`. Outside of the object, you'd use `SomeClass.updateProgress()`.

You can read more about object literals in the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals).

Comment: Thank you both, this makes sense now. I am familiar with object literals. I think the reason I was lost is because in the tutorial itself, this is not wrapped in an object literal. (https://www.urbaninsight.com/2014/10/06/tracking-progress-embedded-vimeo-videos).

Comment: Regarding: "*Within the object, you can refer to the method via `this.updateProgress`*". The function's *this* is set by how it is called (or some use of *bind* that isn't shown) and has nothing to do with how it is created or whether it's "within" an object.

Answer (score 0):

In an object literal expression of the form:

```
{
   // properties ...
}
```

an identifier followed by a colon is the name of a property of the object, and that is then followed by the property value:

```
{
  prop1: value
}
```

a function expression is of the form:

```
function () {
  // function body ...
}
```

and just like any other expression, you could assign that to any variable or property.

So...

```
updateProgress: function () {    
  $.post('/callback', {
    progress: plnzVideoTracker.progress
  });   
}
```

Is (probably) a fragment of an object expression that defines a property named `updateProgress` whose value is the (unnamed) function assigned to it.